# How to make my daughter not to make nose sound while speaking?

Tags: speech

My daughter is 3.5 years old. She doesn't sound few letters like 'L' but 'N' instead. But I believe she will learn that by time.

However few weeks back I noticed that she speaks from her nose (nasal speech). The way she speaks words ending with 'N' or 'M' are different. Eg. she says `Rumb` instead of `Rum`.

Is there any practice or speech therapy we can bring in daily practice to improve her way of speaking?

Comment: Does she seem to have a stuffy nose/allergies/congestion?

Comment: No! she seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that to teach my daughter L sound, first I need to understand the difference between N sound and L sound. I found these 2 videos very helpful to explain me the difference;

- [How to Teach the /l/ sound: Speech Therapy Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-K3nLUThBE)
- [Most common mistake in pronouncing "l" and "n" in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a76I7msAsGE)

I believe she'll improve with practice.

Comment: Update: My daughter is practicing in the way explained in videos. And improved 50%.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take your daughter to a speech therapist for an evaluation.  It's possible that she's going through a normal stage of speech development, or it's possible that she needs a little intervention.  Either way, I think you need a professional opinion before this goes on any longer.

Comment: My daughter mimics the sound and style of other kids unknowingly and quickly (within an hour of play). I believe this is how kids learn. When I correct her words ending with 'm', she pronounce them correctly but then again forget and pronounce them 'mb'. I believe she must be mimicking the style of someone from her school or from rhyme. Though I'm not sure but keeps correcting her.

Answer (score 1):

Kids at that age often have trouble sounding out words, my own daughter used to pronounce 'girl' and a few other words with a 1950's New York accent.

One thing I used to do as an ESL teacher with young Chinese students who couldn't pronounce certain sounds was to find rhymes and tongue twisters for them to say. If it was short and funny it helped them remember and with enough recitations they usually started to improve.

For your childs problem, something like "Rum, tum, tum, my belly is a drum!" while drumming the words out on your belly would do nicely. 
With N, "Nine naughty nobles", isn't as funny but is easy to remember.

Comment: Thanks!! I would love to know more about such tongue twisters and rhyme. I'll give a try. I believe it should help.

Comment: Welcome. My mother had me reciting tongue twisters hundreds of times to deal with my speaking too fast as a child. 
To learn more about tongue twisters and rhymes, do a search for kids rhymes and tongue twisters, and try the ones you think your daughter will like. It's all about trial and error.